# CodeIgniter Active Record - Get number of returned rows

Tags: activerecord, codeigniter

I'm very new to CodeIgniter and Active Record in particular, I know how to do this well in normal SQL but I'm trying to learn.

How can I select some data from one of my tables, and then count how many rows are returned using CodeIgniters Active Record class?

Thanks,
Tom.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Have a look at the result functions [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html):

```
$this->db->from('yourtable');
[... more active record code ...]
$query = $this->db->get();
$rowcount = $query->num_rows();
```

Comment: I was banging my head for hours, I couldn't recall the function's name... and it's not easy to find in official documentation either. I used `print_r` on object resulting from `get_where` method to guess the function's name! =)

Comment: @Residuum can you help me to solve this [query-num-rows-not-returning-correct-number-of-row-when-result-is-not-empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45397106/query-num-rows-not-returning-correct-number-of-row-when-result-is-not-empty)

Answer (score 38):

AND, if you just want to get a count of all the rows in a table

```
$table_row_count = $this->db->count_all('table_name');
```

Answer (score 32):

This goes to you model:

```
public function count_news_by_category($cat)
{
    return $this->db
        ->where('category', $cat)
        ->where('is_enabled', 1)
        ->count_all_results('news');
}
```

It'a an example from my current project.

According to [benchmarking](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/profiling.html) this query works faster than if you do the following:

```
$this->db->select('*')->from('news')->where(...); 
$q = $this->db->get(); 
return $q->num_rows();
```

Answer (score 16):

If you only need the number of rows in a query and don't need the actual row data, use [`count_all_results`](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#CI_DB_query_builder::count_all_results)

```
echo $this->db
       ->where('active',1)
       ->count_all_results('table_name');
```

Answer (score 9):

Just gotta read the docs son!

```
$query->num_rows();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in two different ways:

```
  1. $this->db->query(); //execute the query
     $query = $this->db->get() // get query result
     $count = $query->num_rows() //get current query record.

  2.  $this->db->query(); //execute the query
      $query = $this->db->get() // get query result
      $count = count($query->results()) 
          or   count($query->row_array())  //get current query record.
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$this->db->select('count(id) as rows');
$this->db->from('table_name');
$this->db->where('active',1);
$query = $this->db->get();
foreach($query->result() as $r)
{
   return $r->rows;
}
```

Comment: This causes a `SELECT` query being issued including a `COUNT()` SQL function call. The accepted answer should be taken instead as it prevents this by calling `$query->num_rows()` instead. For example, `num_rows()` of mysqli driver returns the result of `mysqli_num_rows()` PHP function for last query id. Please note: `Not all database drivers have a native way of getting the total number of rows for a result set. When this is the case, all of the data is prefetched and count() is manually called on the resulting array in order to achieve the same result.` (from documentation).

Comment: CI3: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html#result-helper-methods

Answer (score 2):

This is also a very useful function if you are looking for a rows or data with where condition affected

```
function num_rows($table)
    {   
       return $this->db->affected_rows($table);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This code segment for your Model

```
function getCount($tblName){
    $query = $this->db->get($tblName);
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows();
    return $rowCount;       
}
```

This is for controlr

```
  public function index() {
    $data['employeeCount']= $this->CMS_model->getCount("employee");
    $this->load->view("hrdept/main",$data);
}
```

This is for view

```
<div class="count">
  <?php echo $employeeCount; ?>                                                                                            
 </div>
```

This code is used in my project and is working properly.

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

```
function getCount(){
    return $this->db->get('table_name')->num_rows();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT count(id) as value FROM your_table WHERE your_field = ?";
$your_count = $this->db->query($sql, array($your_field))->row(0)->value;
echo $your_count;
```