# How do i get number of rows returned by a query in recordset variable?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$a=$this->db->where('username', $user);
echo $a->num_rows();
```

I have tried this, but getting this error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_driver::num_rows() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Testing\CI\application\models\mymodel.php on line 20
```

Comment: You need to execute your query first. Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222766/codeigniter-active-record-get-number-of-returned-rows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this

```
$a=$this->db->where('username', $user)->get('table_name')->num_rows();
echo $a;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->from('YOUR_TABLE);
$this->db->where('username', $user);
$result = $this->db->get();
echo $result->num_rows();
```

Comment: A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `username` = 'username]'' at line 2

SELECT * WHERE `username` = 'username]'

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\Testing\CI\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330

Comment: You have to specify the table from which you select. `$this->db->from('yourtable');`

Comment: you did not define the SELECT part in your query.. have a look at my edited post

Answer (score 0):

You haven't performed the actual query yet. If you want to perform the query and then find out the number of results, use Yami's answer. If you want to know the number of results before getting the actual results, you can use this:

```
$this->db->where('username', $user);
echo $this->db->count_all_results('yourtable');
```

The latter is useful when you need to do processing which is based on the amount of rows the query returns, for example pagination.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for number of rows returned by your query use,

query->num_rows()//This returns number of affected rows.

Make sure that, you execute this after $this->db->get();

So the sequence of the steps to be executed should be

```
$this->db->select('select condition'); 

$this->db->where('where condition');

$this->db->from('table name');

$Query = $this->db->get();

$Query->num_rows();  //Returns number of rows returned by the query.
```

Refer to [CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html) Manual for more.