# how call a result from database count(*) on CI

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

i got code like this on codeigniter :

```
<?php
 $query = $this->db->query("SELECT count(*) FROM data_pribadi WHERE STATUS = 'diterima'");
 return $query->result();
?>
```

how can i call a result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter Active Record - Get number of returned rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222766/codeigniter-active-record-get-number-of-returned-rows)

Comment: $total = $query->num_rows(); // use num_rows() with db object

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your model.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('data_pribadi');
$this->db->where('STATUS','diterima');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $result=$query->result();
```

And in your Controller, you can seek the results to your view like the below code

```
$this->load->model('Mymodel');
$this->load->view('YourviewName',array($data=>$this->Mymodel->Myfunction()));
```

And these also for your view (example)

```
<?php
foreach ($data as $u):
echo"<option value ='$u->column_name1'>".$u->column_name. "</option>";
endforeach;
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be placed on `model`.

Let me guide you.

**MODEL:**

```
// file name: Mymodel.php
function test() {
    $query = "SELECT count(*) AS total_acc FROM data_pribadi WHERE STATUS = 'diterima'";
    return $this->db->query( $query )->row()->total_acc;
}
```

How about the result?

**CONTROLLER**

```
$this->load->model( 'mymodel' ); //available in CI3
$total_acc = $this->mymodel->test();
echo $total_acc;
```

Done, now you get it. Because your request only produces one row, I think it's suitable for you.

Btw, salam kenal :)